# Select nth-child from last/bottom

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have list of items with alternating background colors. I'm currently using the `:nth-child(odd)` selector to make the alternating row colors. Users have the ability to add new items to the top of the list asynchronously using jquery -- this poses an issue that makes the form a bit unintuitive:

When a new entry is added to the top of the list, all the previously existing rows gets pushed down by one, so they all change alternating colors (since odd rows become even, and vice versa). I'd like to keep the existing alternating colors when a new row is added -- one way to do it would be to calculate odd/even nth-child starting from the bottom of the list... Any way to do this?

Additional info: New entries must be added to 'top' of list. Adding "odd"/"even" class names to rows not practical in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will want to use the `:nth-last-child(2n+0)`.  This is working from the last child instead of the first/newest child.  Hope this helps.